# determining $(this) in jquery

Tags: jquery, this

A common issue I have is getting confused what $(this) is referring to.

I often will try to give it some odd style:

```
$(this).css("border","10px solid red")
```

Which helps sometimes.

I'm stumped with the following however. My question can maybe be answered in two ways:

1) is there a universal way to 'see' what $(this) is referring to in any given situation? Perhaps in combination with firebug?

2) more specifically, any idea what $(this) should be referring to in this sample below? I assumed it would have been the input with a class of btnSave but doesn't seem to be:

```
$(ajaxContainer).find("input.btnSave").click(function(){
    savePanel();
});

function savePanel() {
    $(this).css("border","10px solid red");
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) Use the console in Firebug:

```
var obj = $(this);
console.log(obj);
```

2) savePanel() won't have the context correct to use $(this).  You could try:

```
$(ajaxContainer).find("input.btnSave").click(function(){
    $(this).css("border", "10px solid red");
});
```

Comment: quick edit: I think that should be console.log, right? (That seems to work).

Comment: @DA Yep you're right sorry, I always get them confused! I'll edit the post now :-)

Answer (score 4):

**First question (using Firebug):**

1. Place a breakpoint somewhere in the context you want to investigate (e.g. inside `savePanel()` in your example).
2. When your application hits the breakpoint, add `$(this)` to the watch panel and expand it to view its properties.
3. The first property should be `"0"`, which corresponds to the first DOM node matched by the jQuery object (in this case, `this`).
4. If you hover over the value for `"0"`, Firebug will highlight that DOM node on the page.  If you click the value, Firebug will switch to the HTML tab and scroll to that element.

**Second question:**

- Inside of your anonymous function, `this` will refer to the `<input />` element.
- Inside of `savePanel()`, `this` will refer to the `window` object.

If you want `savePanel()` to have access to the `<input />` element, there are a variety of ways to do it.  The simplest in your case would be to pass it in from the anonymous function:

```
$(ajaxContainer).find("input.btnSave").click(function(){
  savePanel($(this));
});

function savePanel(inputElement) {
  inputElement.css("border","10px solid red");
}
```

Comment: ah! Well, that probably leads to a separate question...how does one attach a function to an elements click event so that when clicked, it'll pass a reference to itself to the function it's calling? (Perhaps that should be a new question here on SO?)

Comment: You should be able to pass the event in and access the target of the click.  Something like what is explained here: [event.target on jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.target)

Comment: thanks, spig. Yea, I should have tried before even asking. To answer my own follow-up question comment in another comment...   savePanel($(this));

Comment: @DA: The easiest thing to do in your case is probably to make the `<input />` element a parameter to `savePanel()`.  I will edit my post with examples.

Answer (score 1):

In your code sample you run into a classic JavaScript problem with a lost context for *this*, since calling another function from an anonymous function will lose the context from the anonymous function ([read more about it here](http://kossovsky.net/index.php/2009/07/function-context-and-apply-function/)). When savePanel is called like you do, *this* will refer to the window object. You can keep the context of *this*, from the event handler, by using [call or apply](http://blog.metawrap.com/blog/TheVeryUsefulJavaScriptCallAndApplyFunctionsForOverridingThisForAGivenFunction.aspx) when delegating the method:

```
$(ajaxContainer).find("input.btnSave").click(function(){
    savePanel.call(this);
});

// OR

$(ajaxContainer).find("input.btnSave").click(function(){
    savePanel.apply(this, arguments);
});

function savePanel() {
    $(this).css("border","10px solid red");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

"this" is javascript is often a source of confusion, because it syntactically looks like a variable and therefore implies the idea of passing it around. Actually, "this" is more like a function and always returns current execution context, that is, the context the current function was called for or applied to.

If i'm not mistaken, jquery tries to execute a callback in the context the callback binder was called, that is

```
 object1.object2.object3.bindSomeCallback(function() {
        object3 will be "this" in the callback
 })
```